# Distributed shared memory

Tags: c, linux, windows, shared-memory, distributed-computing

My current system runs on Linux, with the different tasks using shared memory to access the common data (which is defined as a C struct). The size of the shared data is about 100K.

Now, I want to run the main user interface on Windows, while keeping all the other tasks in Linux, and I’m looking for the best replacement for the shared memory. The refresh rate of the UI is about 10 times per second.

My doubt is if it’s better to do it by myself or to use a third party solution. If I do it on my own, my idea is to open a socket and then use some sort of data serialization between the client (Windows) and the server (Linux).

In the case of third party solutions, I’m a bit overwhelmed by the number of options. After some search, it seems to me that the right solution could be MPI, but I would like to consider other options before start working with it: XDR, OpenMP, JSON, DBus, RDMA, memcached, boost libraries … Has anyone got any experience with any of them? Which are the pros and cons of using such solutions for accessing the shared memory on Linux from Windows?

Maybe MPI or the other third party solutions are too elaborated for such a simple use as mine and I should use a do-it-yourself approach? Any advice if I take that solution? Am I missing something? Am I looking in the wrong direction? I wouldn’t like to reinvent the wheel.

For the file sharing, I’m considering Samba.

My development is done with C and C++, and, of course, the solution needs to be compiled in Linux and Windows.

Comment: One possibility would be to access the Linux UI through something like NX or XVNC.  That would allow you to get at it from a machine running Windows and might be resposive enough for a 10Hz update.

Comment: Explain a bit more what kind of application are you developing!

Comment: I used `memcached` to implement simple cache  over network. And it served my purpose. In your case refresh rate is high. I will suggest you to use udp over tcp, if you opt for `memcached`.

Comment: OpenMP has nothing to do with what you're asking. It's for actual shared-memory multi-processors, i.e. processor cores talking to the same memory bus within one machine.

Comment: I had written OpenMP where I meant MPI, and vivecersa. I've corrected it now.

Comment: Regarding the solutions in the other posts, I had viewed most of them before, but didn't know whether they were better than MPI, but couldn't find any question or paper comparing them. I will study in more deep the options you give me.

Comment: I don't think the remote display is an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using a plain TCP socket between the user interface and the service, with simple tagged message frames passed between the two in preferably architecture-independent manner (i.e. with specific byte order and integer and floating-point types).

On the server end, I'd use a helper process or thread, that maintains two local copies of the shared state struct per client. First one reflects the state the client knows about, and the second one is used to snapshot the shared state at regular intervals. When the two differ, the helper sends the differing fields to the client. Conversely, the client can send modification requests to the helper.

I would not send the 100k shared data structure as a single chunk; it'd be very inefficient. Also, assuming the state contains multiple fields, having the client send the entire new 100k state would overwrite fields not meant to by the client.

I'd use one message for each field in the state, or atomically manipulated set of fields. The message structure itself should be very simple. At minimum, each message should start with a fixed-size length and type fields, so that it is trivial to receive the messages. It is always a good idea to leave the possibility of later extending the capabilities/fields, without breaking backwards compatibility, too.

You don't need a lot of code to implement the above. You do need some accessor/manipulator code for each different type of field in the state (char, short, int, long, double, float, and any other type or struct you might use), and that (and the helper that compares the active state with the simulated user state) will probably be the bulk of the code.

Although I don't normally recommend reinventing the wheel, in this case I do recommend writing your own message passing code, directly on top of TCP, simply because all the libraries I know of that could be used for this, are rather unwieldy or would impose some design choices I'd rather leave to the application.

If you want, I can provide some example code that would hopefully illustrate this better. I don't have Windows, but Qt does have a QTcpSocket class you can use that works the same in both Linux and Windows, so there shouldn't be (m)any differences. In fact, if you design the message structure well, you could write the UI in some other language like Python, without any differences to the server itself.

---

Promised examples follow; apologies for maximum-length post.

Paired counters are useful when there is a single writer for a specific field, possibly many readers, and you wish to add minimal overhead to the write path. Reading never blocks, and a reader will see whether they got a valid copy or if an update was in progress and they should not rely on the value they saw. (This also allows reliable write semantics for a field in an async-signal-safe context, where pthread locking is not guaranteed to work.)

This implementation works best on GCC-4.7 and later, but should work with earlier C compilers, too. Legacy __sync built-ins also work with Intel, Pathscale, and PGI C compilers. **counter.h**:

```
#ifndef   COUNTER_H
#define   COUNTER_H

/*
 * Atomic generation counter support.
 *
 * A generation counter allows a single writer thread to
 * locklessly modify a value non-atomically, while letting
 * any number of reader threads detect the change. Reader
 * threads can also check if the value they observed is
 * "atomic", or taken during a modification in progress.
 *
 * There is no protection against multiple concurrent writers.
 *
 * If the writer gets canceled or dies during an update,
 * the counter will get garbled. Reinitialize before relying
 * on such a counter.
 *
 * There is no guarantee that a reader will observe an
 * "atomic" value, if the writer thread modifies the value
 * more often than the reader thread can read it.
 *
 * Two typical use cases:
 *
 *  A) A single writer requires minimum overhead/latencies,
 *     whereas readers can poll and retry if necessary
 *
 *  B) Non-atomic value or structure modified in
 *     an interrupt context (async-signal-safe)
 *
 * Initialization:
 *
 *      Counter counter = COUNTER_INITIALIZER;
 *
 *      or
 *
 *      Counter counter;
 *      counter_init(&counter);
 *
 * Write sequence:
 *
 *      counter_acquire(&counter);
 *      (modify or write value)
 *      counter_release(&counter);
 *
 * Read sequence:
 *
 *      unsigned int check;
 *      check = counter_before(&counter);
 *      (obtain a copy of the value)
 *      if (check == counter_after(&counter))
 *          (a copy of the value is atomic)
 *
 * Read sequence with spin-waiting,
 * will spin forever if counter garbled:
 *
 *      unsigned int check;
 *      do {
 *          check = counter_before(&counter);
 *          (obtain a copy of the value)
 *      } while (check != counter_after(&counter));
 *
 * All these are async-signal-safe, and will never block
 * (except for the spinning loop just above, obviously).
*/

typedef struct {
    volatile unsigned int  value[2];
} Counter;
#define COUNTER_INITIALIZER {{0U,0U}}

#if (__GNUC__ > 4) || (__GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ >= 7)
/*
 * GCC 4.7 and later provide __atomic built-ins.
 * These are very efficient on x86 and x86-64.
*/

static inline void counter_init(Counter *const counter)
{
    /* This is silly; assignments should suffice. */
    do {
        __atomic_store_n(&(counter->value[1]), 0U, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
        __atomic_store_n(&(counter->value[0]), 0U, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
    } while (__atomic_load_n(&(counter->value[0]), __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST) |
             __atomic_load_n(&(counter->value[1]), __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST));
}

static inline unsigned int counter_before(Counter *const counter)
{
    return __atomic_load_n(&(counter->value[1]), __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
}

static inline unsigned int counter_after(Counter *const counter)
{
    return __atomic_load_n(&(counter->value[0]), __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
}

static inline unsigned int counter_acquire(Counter *const counter)
{
    return __atomic_fetch_add(&(counter->value[0]), 1U, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
}

static inline unsigned int counter_release(Counter *const counter)
{
    return __atomic_fetch_add(&(counter->value[1]), 1U, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
}

#else
/*
 * Rely on legacy __sync built-ins.
 *
 * Because there is no __sync_fetch(),
 * counter_before() and counter_after() are safe,
 * but not optimal (especially on x86 and x86-64).
*/

static inline void counter_init(Counter *const counter)
{
    /* This is silly; assignments should suffice. */
    do {
        counter->value[0] = 0U;
        counter->value[1] = 0U;
        __sync_synchronize();
    } while (__sync_fetch_and_add(&(counter->value[0]), 0U) |
             __sync_fetch_and_add(&(counter->value[1]), 0U));
}

static inline unsigned int counter_before(Counter *const counter)
{
    return __sync_fetch_and_add(&(counter->value[1]), 0U);
}

static inline unsigned int counter_after(Counter *const counter)
{
    return __sync_fetch_and_add(&(counter->value[0]), 0U);
}

static inline unsigned int counter_acquire(Counter *const counter)
{
    return __sync_fetch_and_add(&(counter->value[0]), 1U);
}

static inline unsigned int counter_release(Counter *const counter)
{
    return __sync_fetch_and_add(&(counter->value[1]), 1U);
}

#endif

#endif /* COUNTER_H */
```

Each shared state field type needs their own structure defined. For our purposes, I'll just use a `Value` structure to describe one of them. It is up to you to define all the needed Field and Value types to match your needs. For example, a 3D vector of double precision floating-point components would be

```
typedef struct {
    double    x;
    double    y;
    double    z;
} Value;

typedef struct {
    Counter   counter;
    Value     value;
} Field;
```

where the modifying thread uses e.g.

```
void set_field(Field *const field, Value *const value)
{
    counter_acquire(&field->counter);
    field->value = value;
    counter_release(&field->counter);
}
```

and each reader maintains their own local shapshot using e.g.

```
typedef enum {
    UPDATED = 0,
    UNCHANGED = 1,
    BUSY = 2
} Updated;

Updated check_field(Field *const local, const Field *const shared)
{
    Field cache;

    cache.counter[0] = counter_before(&shared->counter);

    /* Local counter check allows forcing an update by
     * simply changing one half of the local counter.
     * If you don't need that, omit the local-only part. */
    if (local->counter[0] == local->counter[1] &&
        cache.counter[0] == local->counter[0])
        return UNCHANGED;

    cache.value = shared->value;

    cache.counter[1] = counter_after(&shared->counter);
    if (cache.counter[0] != cache.counter[1])
        return BUSY;

    *local = cache;

    return UPDATED;
}
```

Note that the `cache` above constitutes one local copy of the value, so each reader only needs to maintain one copy of the fields it is interested in. Also, the above accessor function only modifies `local` with a successful snapshot.

---

When using pthread locking, `pthread_rwlock_t` is a good option, as long as the programmer understands the priority issues with multiple readers and writers. (`see man pthread_rwlock_rdlock` and `man pthread_rwlock_wrlock` for details.)

Personally, I would just stick to mutexes with as short holding times as possible, to reduce overall complexity. The Field structure for a mutex-protected change-counted value I'd use would probably be something like

```
typedef struct {
    pthread_mutex_t        mutex;
    Value                  value;
    volatile unsigned int  change;
} Field;

void set_field(Field *const field, const Value *const value)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&field->mutex);
    field->value = *value;
#if (__GNUC__ > 4) || (__GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ >= 7)
    __atomic_fetch_add(&field->change, 1U, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
#else
    __sync_fetch_and_add(&field->change, 1U);
#endif
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&field->mutex);
}

void get_field(Field *const local, Field *const field)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&field->mutex);
    local->value = field->value;
#if (__GNUC__ > 4) || (__GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ >= 7)
    local->value = __atomic_fetch_n(&field->change, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
#else
    local->value = __sync_fetch_and_add(&field->change, 0U);
#endif
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&field->mutex);
}

Updated check_field(Field *const local, Field *const shared)
{
#if (__GNUC__ > 4) || (__GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ >= 7)
    if (local->change == __atomic_fetch_n(&field->change, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST))
        return UNCHANGED;
#else
    if (local->change == __sync_fetch_and_add(&field->change, 0U))
        return UNCHANGED;
#endif
    pthread_mutex_lock(&shared->mutex);
    local->value = shared->value;
#if (__GNUC__ > 4) || (__GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ >= 7)
    local->change = __atomic_fetch_n(&field->change, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
#else
    local->change = __sync_fetch_and_add(&field->change, 0U);
#endif
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&shared->mutex);
}
```

Note that the mutex field in the local copy is unused, and can be omitted from the local copy (defining a suitable Cache etc. structure type without it).

The semantics with respect to the *change* field are simple: It is always accessed atomically, and can therefore be read without holding the mutex. It is only modified while holding the mutex (but because readers do not hold the mutex, it must be modified atomically even then).

Note that if your server is restricted to x86 or x86-64 architectures, you can use ordinary accesses to *change* above (e.g. `field->change++`), as `unsigned int` access is atomic on these architectures; no need to use built-in functions. (Although increment is non-atomic, readers will only ever see the old or the new `unsigned int`, so that's not a problem either.)

---

On the server, you'll need some kind of "agent" process or thread, acting on behalf of the remote clients, sending field changes to each client, and optionally receiving field contents for update from each client.

Efficient implementation of such an agent is a big question. A properly thought-out recommendation would require more detailed information on the system. The simplest possible implementation, I guess, would be a low-priority thread simply scanning the shared state continuously, reporting any field changes not known to each client as it sees them. If change rate is high -- say, usually more than a dozen changes per second over the entire state -- then that may be quite acceptable. If change rate varies, adding a global change counter (modified whenever a single field is modified, i.e. in `set_field()`) and sleeping (or at least yielding) when no global change is observed, is better.

If there are multiple remote clients, I would use a single agent, which collects changes into a queue, with a cached copy of the state as seen at the head of the queue (with previous changes being those that lead up to it). Initially connected clients get the entire state, then each queued change following that. Note that the queue entries do not need to represent fields as such, but the messages sent to each client to update that field, and that if a latter update replaces an already queued value, the already queued value can be removed, reducing the amount of data that needs to be sent to clients that are catching up. This is an interesting topic on its own, and would warrant a question of its own, in my opinion.

---

Like I mentioned above, I would personally use a plain TCP socket between the user interface and the service.

There are four main issues with respect to the TCP messages:

1. Byte order and data formats (unless both server and remote clients are guaranteed to use the same hardware architecture)

   My preferred solution is to use native byte order (but well-defined standard types) when sending, with recipient doing any byte order conversions. This requires that each end sends an initial message with predetermined *"prototype values"* for each integer and floating-point type used.

   I assume integers use two's complement format with no padding bits, and double and float are double- and single-precision IEEE-754 types, respectively. Most current hardware architectures have these natively (although byte ordering does vary). Weird architectures can and do emulate these in software, typically by supplying suitable command-line switches or using some libraries.
2. Message framing (as TCP is a stream of bytes, not a stream of packets, from the application perspective)

   Most robust option is to prefix each message with a fixed size type field and a fixed size length field. (Usually, the length field indicates how many additional bytes are part of this message, and will include any possible padding bytes the sender might have added.)

   The recipient will receive TCP input until it has enough cached for the fixed type and length parts to examine the complete packet length. Then it receives more data, until it has a full TCP packet. A minimal receive buffer implementation is something like
3. Extensibility

   Backwards compatibility is essential for making updates and upgrades easier. This means you'll probably need to include some kind of version number in the initial message from server to client, and have both server and client ignore messages they do not know. (This obviously requires a length field in each message, as recipients cannot infer the length of messages they do not recognize.)

   In some cases you might need the ability to mark a message important, in the sense that if the recipient does not recognize it, further communications should be aborted. This is easiest to achieve by using some kind of identifier or bit in the type field. For example, [PNG file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#.22Chunks.22_within_the_file) is very similar to the message format I've described here, with a four-byte (four ASCII character) type field, and a four-byte (32-bit) length field for each message (*"chunk"*). If the first type character is uppercase ASCII, it means it is a critical one.
4. Passing initial state

   Passing the initial state as a single chunk fixes the entire shared state structure. Instead, I recommend passing each field or record separately, just as if they were updates. Optionally, when all the initial fields have been sent, you can send a message that informs the client they have the entire state; this should let the client first receive the complete state, then construct and render the user interface, without having to dynamically adjust to varying number of fields.

   Whether each client requires the full state, or just a smaller subset of the state, is another question. When a remote client connects to a server, it probably should include some kind of identifier the server can use to make that determination.

Here is **messages.h**, a header file with inline implementation of integer and floating-point type handling and byte order detection:

```
#ifndef   MESSAGES_H
#define   MESSAGES_H

#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#if defined(__GNUC__)
static const struct __attribute__((packed)) {
#else
#pragma pack(push,1)
#endif
    const uint64_t  u64;        /* Offset +0 */
    const int64_t   i64;        /*        +8 */
    const double    dbl;        /*       +16 */
    const uint32_t  u32;        /*       +24 */
    const int32_t   i32;        /*       +28 */
    const float     flt;        /*       +32 */
    const uint16_t  u16;        /*       +36 */
    const int16_t   i16;        /*       +38 */
} prototypes = {
    18364758544493064720ULL,    /* u64 */
    -1311768465156298103LL,     /* i64 */
    0.71948481353325643983254167324048466980457305908203125,
    3735928559UL,               /* u32 */
    -195951326L,                /* i32 */
    1.06622731685638427734375f, /* flt */
    51966U,                     /* u16 */
    -7658                       /* i16 */
};
#if !defined(__GNUC__)
#pragma pack(pop)
#endif

/* Add prototype section to a buffer.
*/
size_t add_prototypes(unsigned char *const data, const size_t size)
{
    if (size < sizeof prototypes) {
        errno = ENOSPC;
        return 0;
    } else {
        memcpy(data, &prototypes, sizeof prototypes);
        return sizeof prototypes;
    }
}

/*
 * Byte order manipulation functions.
*/
static void reorder64(void *const dst, const void *const src, const int order)
{
    if (order) {
        uint64_t  value;
        memcpy(&value, src, 8);
        if (order & 1)
            value = ((value >>  8U) & 0x00FF00FF00FF00FFULL)
                  | ((value & 0x00FF00FF00FF00FFULL) <<  8U);
        if (order & 2)
            value = ((value >> 16U) & 0x0000FFFF0000FFFFULL)
                  | ((value & 0x0000FFFF0000FFFFULL) << 16U);
        if (order & 4)
            value = ((value >> 32U) & 0x00000000FFFFFFFFULL)
                  | ((value & 0x00000000FFFFFFFFULL) << 32U);
        memcpy(dst, &value, 8);
    } else
    if (dst != src)
        memmove(dst, src, 8);
}

static void reorder32(void *const dst, const void *const src, const int order)
{
    if (order) {
        uint32_t  value;
        memcpy(&value, src, 4);
        if (order & 1)
            value = ((value >>  8U) & 0x00FF00FFUL)
                  | ((value & 0x00FF00FFUL) <<  8U);
        if (order & 2)
            value = ((value >> 16U) & 0x0000FFFFUL)
                  | ((value & 0x0000FFFFUL) << 16U);
        memcpy(dst, &value, 4);
    } else
    if (dst != src)
        memmove(dst, src, 4);
}

static void reorder16(void *const dst, const void *const src, const int order)
{
    if (order & 1) {
        const unsigned char c[2] = { ((const unsigned char *)src)[0],
                                     ((const unsigned char *)src)[1] };
        ((unsigned char *)dst)[0] = c[1];
        ((unsigned char *)dst)[1] = c[0];
    } else
    if (dst != src)
        memmove(dst, src, 2);
}

/* Detect byte order conversions needed.
 *
 * If the prototypes cannot be supported, returns -1.
 *
 * If prototype record uses native types, returns 0.
 *
 * Otherwise, bits 0..2 are the integer order conversion,
 * and bits 3..5 are the floating-point order conversion.
 * If 'order' is the return value, use
 *      reorderXX(local, remote, order)
 * for integers, and
 *      reorderXX(local, remote, order/8)
 * for floating-point types.
 *
 * For adjusting records sent to server, just do the same,
 * but with order obtained by calling this function with
 * parameters swapped.
*/
int detect_order(const void *const native, const void *const other)
{
    const unsigned char *const  source = other;
    const unsigned char *const  target = native;
    unsigned char               temp[8];
    int                         iorder = 0;
    int                         forder = 0;

    /* Verify the size of the types.
     * C89/C99/C11 says sizeof (char) == 1, but check that too. */
    if (sizeof (double) != 8 ||
        sizeof (int64_t) != 8 ||
        sizeof (uint64_t) != 8 ||
        sizeof (float) != 4 ||
        sizeof (int32_t) != 4 ||
        sizeof (uint32_t) != 4 ||
        sizeof (int16_t) != 2 ||
        sizeof (uint16_t) != 2 ||
        sizeof (unsigned char) != 1 ||
        sizeof prototypes != 40)
        return -1;

    /* Find byte order for the largest floating-point type. */
    while (1) {
        reorder64(temp, source + 16, forder);
        if (!memcmp(temp, target + 16, 8))
            break;
        if (++forder >= 8)
            return -1;
    }

    /* Verify forder works for all other floating-point types. */
    reorder32(temp, source + 32, forder);
    if (memcmp(temp, target + 32, 4))
        return -1;

    /* Find byte order for the largest integer type. */
    while (1) {
        reorder64(temp, source + 0, iorder);
        if (!memcmp(temp, target + 0, 8))
            break;
        if (++iorder >= 8)
            return -1;
    }
    /* Verify iorder works for all other integer types. */
    reorder64(temp, source + 8, iorder);
    if (memcmp(temp, target + 8, 8))
        return -1;
    reorder32(temp, source + 24, iorder);
    if (memcmp(temp, target + 24, 4))
        return -1;
    reorder32(temp, source + 28, iorder);
    if (memcmp(temp, target + 28, 4))
        return -1;
    reorder16(temp, source + 36, iorder);
    if (memcmp(temp, target + 36, 2))
        return -1;
    reorder16(temp, source + 38, iorder);
    if (memcmp(temp, target + 38, 2))
        return -1;

    /* Everything works. */
    return iorder + 8 * forder;
}

/* Verify current architecture is supportable.
 * This could be a compile-time check.
 *
 * (The buffer contains prototypes for network byte order,
 *  and actually returns the order needed to convert from
 *  native to network byte order.)
 *
 * Returns -1 if architecture is not supported,
 * a nonnegative (0 or positive) value if successful.
*/
static int verify_architecture(void)
{
    static const unsigned char network_endian[40] = {
        254U, 220U, 186U, 152U, 118U,  84U,  50U,  16U, /* u64 */
        237U, 203U, 169U, 135U, 238U, 204U, 170U, 137U, /* i64 */
         63U, 231U,   6U,   5U,   4U,   3U,   2U,   1U, /* dbl */
        222U, 173U, 190U, 239U,                         /* u32 */
        244U,  82U,   5U,  34U,                         /* i32 */
         63U, 136U, 122U,  35U,                         /* flt */
        202U, 254U,                                     /* u16 */
        226U,  22U,                                     /* i16 */
    };

    return detect_order(&prototypes, network_endian);
}

#endif /* MESSAGES_H */
```

Here is an example function that a sender can use to pack a 3-component vector identified by a 32-bit unsigned integer, into a 36-byte message. This uses a message frame starting with four bytes ("`Vec3`"), followed by the 32-bit frame length, followed by the 32-bit identifier, followed by three doubles:

```
size_t add_vector(unsigned char *const data, const size_t size,
                  const uint32_t id,
                  const double x, const double y, const double z)
{
    const uint32_t length = 4 + 4 + 4 + 8 + 8 + 8;

    if (size < (size_t)bytes) {
        errno = ENOSPC;
        return 0;
    }

    /* Message identifier, four bytes */
    buffer[0] = 'V';
    buffer[1] = 'e';
    buffer[2] = 'c';
    buffer[3] = '3';

    /* Length field, uint32_t */
    memcpy(buffer + 4, &length, 4);

    /* Identifier, uint32_t */
    memcpy(buffer + 8, &id, 4);

    /* Vector components */
    memcpy(buffer + 12, &x, 8);
    memcpy(buffer + 20, &y, 8);
    memcpy(buffer + 28, &z, 8);

    return length;
}
```

Personally, I prefer shorter, 16-bit identifiers and 16-bit length; that also limits maximum message length to 65536 bytes, making 65536 bytes a good read/write buffer size.

The recipient can handle the received TCP data stream for example thus:

```
static unsigned char *input_data;  /* Data buffer */
static size_t         input_size;  /* Data buffer size */
static unsigned char *input_head;  /* Next byte in buffer */
static unsigned char *input_tail;  /* After last buffered byte */
static int            input_order; /* From detect_order() */

/* Function to handle "Vec3" messages: */
static void handle_vec3(unsigned char *const msg)
{
    uint32_t id;
    double   x, y, z;

    reorder32(&id, msg+8, input_order);

    reorder64(&x, msg+12, input_order/8);
    reorder64(&y, msg+20, input_order/8);
    reorder64(&z, msg+28, input_order/8);

    /* Do something with vector id, x, y, z. */
}

/* Function that tries to consume thus far buffered
 * input data -- typically run once after each
 * successful TCP receive. */
static void consume(void)
{
    while (input_head + 8 < input_tail) {
        uint32_t length;

        /* Get current packet length. */
        reorder32(&length, input_head + 4, input_order);
        if (input_head + length < input_tail)
            break; /* Not all read, yet. */

        /* We have a full packet! */

        /* Handle "Vec3" packet: */
        if (input_head[0] == 'V' &&
            input_head[1] == 'e' &&
            input_head[2] == 'c' &&
            input_head[3] == '3')
            handle_vec3(input_head);

        /* Advance to next packet. */
        input_head += length;
    }

    if (input_head < input_tail) {
        /* Move partial message to start of buffer. */
        if (input_head > input_data) {
            const size_t have = input_head - input_data;
            memmove(input_data, input_head, have);
            input_head = input_data;
            input_tail = input_data + have;
        }
    } else {
        /* Buffer is empty. */
        input_head = input_data;
        input_tail = input_data;
    }
}
```

Questions?

Comment: I think I'll finally use your approach. Can you please provide that example code? Do you know of any tool/library for the comparison between the two local copies?I've been looking at memcached and MPI and I think it'll be quite a lot of work to make them do what I want, if I ever manage to do it.  I already have a TCP server (with Qt) running on the Linux side.

Comment: @Asier: What types (ints? floats? doubles? structures? strings?) are the fields in your shared state struct?

Comment: My data struct uses all kind of types. Do you know what to use in the comparison of the local copies?

Comment: @Asier: Atomicity is an issue; you do not want to propagate partial field values. If each field or group of fields is modified only by one (thread), then paired generation counters (one modified before update, the other after the update) is one option, and also allows fast change detection (just by comparing the counter value). I suspect that might work for you, too. Do you prefer an example using paired counters, `pthread_mutex_t` locking, or `pthread_rwlock_t` locking?

Comment: I haven't used paired counters yet, so it'd be fine if you could send the example with them. If I later decide to use locks, I don't expect to have problems. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ok. Paired counters work when there is a single modifier thread, but possibly many readers. I'll cook up an example later today.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. I'll give it a try. Sadly, I'm with another project at this moment and can't work on this issue now. I've studied the solution and it seems to give me all the foundings I need to start the development. Now, I think my biggest problem will be to define logical groups for the counters so that I don't have to use a counter for each value. Thanks again

Comment: Had to upvote because no one else has.  This is one of the reasons I don't come on SO that much anymore.  People don't appreciate anything.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK (but I don't know Windows) you cannot [share *memory*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory) (à la [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html)) on both Linux and Windows at once (you could share data, using some network protocol, this is what [memcached](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcached) does).

However, you can make a Linux process answering to network messages from a Windows machine (but that is not shared memory!).

Did you consider using a Web interface? You could add a web interface -with [ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) techniques- on Linux (to your Linux software), e.g. using [FastCGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI) or an HTTP server library like [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) or [wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt). Then your Windows users could use their browser to interact with your program (which would still run on some Linux compute server).

PS. Read the wikipage on [distributed shared memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_shared_memory). It means something different than what you are asking! Read also about [message passing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing)!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will have a deeper look into memcached. Is it possible to use the web interface with a C++ program (Qt 5.2) in the Windows side?

Comment: It seems that you are a bit confused. AFAIK, Qt does not provide a web interface. But Wt does (and is similar to Qt, as programming style). I don't think that you need to look inside `memcached`, it is just an example of a Linux server program (illustrating that data can be shared, but memory cannot be shared, between Linux & Windows).

Comment: I've found many options, but none fitted my case. So I guess I am a bit confused. I need to look deeper into memcached and see if it is not what I need (I understood in your previous post, as well as in Sanket's post, that it could be a solution).  My main UI in Windows will run Qt. However, I will also have a look at wt. Thank you

Comment: `memcached` was originally mentioned in your question. I have no idea if it is a valid solution to your issue (I guess that not). And *MPI* is about *message passing* not about *shared memory*.